# YeSQL with connection pool?

Tags: clojure

I'm checking if YeSQL may help in my Clojure project, but I cannot find any example of YeSQL using a connection pool.

does this mean that YeSQL creates a new connection to every statement?

I also found an example on how to use transactions using clojure.java.jdbc/with-db-transaction, but I feel it is outdated (I haven't tried yet).

does this mean that YeSQL depends on clojure.java.jdbc to commit/rollback control? in this case, shouldn't I just use clojure.java.jdbc alone, since YeSQL doesn't offer too much more (other than naming my queries and externalizing them)?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

YeSQL doesn't handle connections or connection pooling. You need to handle it externally and provide a connection instance to the query function.

As you can see from the YeSQL example from [README](https://github.com/krisajenkins/yesql/blob/master/README.md#one-file-one-query):

```
; Define a database connection spec. (This is standard clojure.java.jdbc.)
(def db-spec {:classname "org.postgresql.Driver"
              :subprotocol "postgresql"
              :subname "//localhost:5432/demo"
              :user "me"})

; Use it standalone. Note that the first argument is the db-spec.
(users-by-country db-spec "GB")
;=> ({:count 58})

; Use it in a clojure.java.jdbc transaction.
(require '[clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc])
(jdbc/with-db-transaction [connection db-spec]
   {:limeys (users-by-country connection "GB")
    :yanks  (users-by-country connection "US")})
```

If you ask how to add connection pool handling you might check an example from [Clojure Cookbook](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/06_databases/6-02_SQL-database-connection-pooling.asciidoc).

As for the transaction handling, YeSQL documentation is none, but [source](https://github.com/krisajenkins/yesql/blob/9124ce779df4f8e2d79b83d3023b9460f26fae37/src/yesql/types.clj#L51) is quite easy to understand:

```
(defn- emit-query-fn
  "Emit function to run a query.
   - If the query name ends in `!` it will call `clojure.java.jdbc/execute!`,
   - If the query name ends in `<!` it will call `clojure.java.jdbc/insert!`,
   - otherwise `clojure.java.jdbc/query` will be used."
  [{:keys [name docstring statement]}]
  (let [split-query (split-at-parameters statement)
        {:keys [query-args display-args function-args]} (split-query->args split-query)
        jdbc-fn (cond
                 (= [\< \!] (take-last 2 name)) `insert-handler
                 (= \! (last name)) `execute-handler
                 :else `jdbc/query)]
    `(def ~(fn-symbol (symbol name) docstring statement display-args)
       (fn [db# ~@function-args]
         (~jdbc-fn db#
                   (reassemble-query '~split-query
                                     ~query-args))))))
```

So it will just generate a function that will either call `clojure.java.jdbc/execute!` or `clojure.java.jdbc/insert!` with the generated query. You might need to refer to those functions' documentation for further details.

Comment: i think this is part of the problem... i don't see how yesql can yeild a query but only execute one.

Comment: Yes, YeSQL is just a library for externalizing your SQL code and generating runtime functions for executing it. It uses `clojure.java.jdbc` for executing the queries and statements.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "I don't see how yesql can yield a query but only execute one" - YeSQL doesn't need to generate any SQL queries as you write them by yourself in SQL files. YeSQL will just generate handy functions to execute SQL code from those files as ordinary Clojure functions.

Comment: sorry, i should have been more clear;  `jdbc/execute!` requires params such as 'database connection' and sql to execute.  In place of the database connection, i can put in a call to a db-pool with c3p0.  I couldn't figure out anyway to do that with `yesql`, because `users-by-country` (for instance) requires a db-spec and wants to make its own connection at query execution time.

Comment: The 'database connection' that you are supposed to pass to `jdbc/*` functions is actually a db-spec as described in http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/connection_pooling.html. You just need to create a db-spec as `{:datasource <your-pool-datasource-object>}` and use it in place of `db connection` argument to `jdbc/*` functions. That way you don't need to borrow connections manually from the pool but `jdbc` functions/macros (including `with-db-connection` where you also pass db-spec) will do that for you.

Answer (score 3):

When doing transactions using YesQL, I wrap the YesQL calls in a clojure.java.jdbc/with-db-transation invocation, and pass the generated connection details in to the YesQL function call, which they'll use instead of the standard non-transaction connection if supplied. For example:

```
;; supply a name for the transaction connection, t-con, based on the existing db connection
(jdbc/with-db-transaction [t-con db-spec] 
  ;; this is the yesql call with a second map specifying the transaction connection
  (create-client-order<! {...} {:connection t-con}))
```

All wrapped YesQL calls using the `{:connection t-con}` map will be part of the same transaction.